# Showing the triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ is isosceles if $\frac{c-b}{a} + \frac{a-c}{b} + \frac{b-a}{c} = 0$

Tags: geometry

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be the sides of a triangle and 
>   $$\frac{c-b}{a} + \frac{a-c}{b} + \frac{b-a}{c} = 0$$ 
>   Show that the triangle is isosceles.

A simple way of solving this, would be getting the fractions on common denominator and multiplying by $abc$. We obtain a second degree equation, which solving for $c$ gives us two roots: $c = a$ and $c = b$.

> Is there any other way of solving the problem?

Comment: Actually, the equation obtained from the method you mention is $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$. It is not necessary for $c$ to equal $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Blue, a generous interpretation of OPs statement is "if the equation is a quadratic in c, meaning $a \neq b$, then the quadratic formula yields $c=a,b$ as roots."

Comment: Calvin, that's what I meant. However, Blue's answer is simple and elegant. Is there a more geometric way to solve the problem by using the properties of triangles?

Comment: Vlad Radu, LHS of relation is zero if each fraction is zero, that is a=b=c.